# Drawing Multiple Canvas Elements Using JavaScript and HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I want to draw 4 canvas elements. That is to say, I want to draw the same canvas element, 4 times.

Using an id attached to one canvas element, I am able to get it and draw it successfully.

from **main.js**

```
    var canvas = document.getElementById('box');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var radius = 75;
    var endPercent = 99;
    var curPercent = 0;

    ctx.lineWidth = "10";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";

    function draw(currentPerc){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc('100', '100', radius, 0, curPercent*currentPerc, false);
        ctx.stroke();

        curPercent++
            if(curPercent < endPercent){
                requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                    draw(curPercent/100);
                });
            }
    }
    draw();
```

from **HomePage.js**

```
 <canvas id="box" width="200" height="200" ></canvas>
```

In beginning to work out how I'd go about drawing this four times, I tried the following:

First in HomePage.js I added 4 canvas elements with a class name of the same id name.

from **HomePage.js**

```
<canvas class="box" width="200" height="200" ></canvas>
<canvas class="box" width="200" height="200" ></canvas>
<canvas class="box" width="200" height="200" ></canvas>
<canvas class="box" width="200" height="200" ></canvas>
```

then in the javascript I tried the following:

from **Main.js**

```
 var canvasCollect = document.querySelectorAll('canvas.box');
 canvasCollect.forEach(draw());

var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var radius = 75;
var endPercent = 99;
var curPercent = 0;

ctx.lineWidth = "10";
ctx.strokeStyle = "green";

function draw(currentPerc){
    ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc('100', '100', radius, 0, curPercent*currentPerc, false);
    ctx.stroke();

    curPercent++
        if(curPercent < endPercent){
            requestAnimationFrame(function(){
                draw(curPercent/100);
            });
        }
}
```

This isn't working.  Nothing is rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each instance of a HTMLCanvasElement has it's own 2D rendering context. If we take a look inside your `draw()` function we can see the following lines:

```
ctx.clearRect(0,0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc('100', '100', radius, 0, curPercent*currentPerc, false);
ctx.stroke();
```

**ctx** is a variable pointing to the CanvasRenderingContext2D of your `<canvas>` element with the id '**box**'.

So as it is, the draw() function would merely draw to this single canvas. To make it draw to any canvas of class `box`, you need to address each's own 2D rendering context.

Here's an example:

```js
var canvasCollect = document.querySelectorAll('canvas.box');

var radius = 75;
var endPercent = 100;
var curPercent = 0;

function draw() {
  var ctx;
  canvasCollect.forEach(canvas => {
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    ctx.lineWidth = "10";
    ctx.strokeStyle = "green";
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc('100', '100', radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI * curPercent / 100, false);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.closePath();
  });

  curPercent++;
  if (curPercent <= endPercent) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() {
      draw(curPercent);
    });
  }
}

draw(curPercent);
```

```html
<canvas class="box" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas class="box" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas class="box" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
<canvas class="box" width="200" height="200"></canvas>
```